# Multiple sites on Apache2

Tags: apache2

I'm following instructions from this url on running multiple sites on Apache2

```
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-18-04/
```

Instructions are for 2 sites but i need to run 3 sites. I followed all steps and created three different folders for each site in my www folder and three different `domain.com.conf` files in `sites-available` folder. If i enable all three domains using `a2ensite` then my apache2 service gives error on restart but if i enable only 2 sites then my apache service run OK and i can visit my sites in browser. Even with two sites enable i can still visit my all three sites on browser but i only see two conf files in `sites-enabled` folder. Once i enable all three sites i get three conf files in `sites-enabled` folder but apache service won't restart. Error i get when restarting apache2 service is as follow..

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-02-21 04:10:28 UTC; 8s ago
Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
Process: 23325 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

status says

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-02-21 04:10:28 UTC; 1min 31s ago
Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
Process: 23325 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
apachectl[23336]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax e>
apachectl[23325]: Action 'start' failed.
apachectl[23325]: The Apache error log may have more information.
systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

even though all my three sites are running with 2 sites enabled but i still like to enable all three sites and restart apache2 service.

I'm running apache2 on ubuntu server 20.04 LTS

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

My domain1.com.conf file is as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com

</VirtualHost>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Other three config files are same except site2, site3 and domain2, domain3.

Another thing i found is apache2 service restart error comes only when i run `e2ensite` command on domain1 (site1) only. If i only have site2 and sit3 enabled then i don't get apache2 service error. This tells me that there is something wrong with site1 only.

Comment: From the error logs you shared, the problem is a syntax error on line 225 of your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file. I would suggest looking there first to see if there’s an unnecessary semi-colon or a mid-named XML attribute.

Comment: I never edited apache2.conf file. It is same as original. apache2.conf line 225 is IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

Comment: Then the syntax issue is in the config file for that third site. Without seeing how you’ve configured things, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I just tested few more things. I used a2dissite command for all my three sites indlucing 000-default site. Currently i don't have any conf file in my sites-enabled folder. All my three sites are running fine in browser. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: It would be better to update your question with additional info rather than posting updates in the comments. It’s also important to remember to `sudo service apache2 reload` (or `restart`) after using any of the `a2` commands, otherwise the configuration is not reloaded.

Comment: Thank you Matigo for your time and support. Issue was with my domain1.com.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I had additional `</VirtualHost>` tag by mistake in my `domain1.com.conf` file. You suppose to have it twice like open and close tag but in my file i had this tag again in the middle and i didn't pay attention to it, maybe it got too late working on this last night. Fix the file and all three sites are working fine. Apache2 service is also restarting without any errors. Your original `000-default-conf` should look like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias www.domain1.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Run `a2ensite <domain name>` on all your sites. Restart apache2 service by running `sudo systemctl restart apache2`. Check `sites-enabled` folder and it should show your conf file pointers. Make sure you got your multiple sites placed in their respective folders in `/var/www` folder prior to this.